# TeX4ht: Strange behavior when I include `\xymatrix` in a macro

Tags: macros, tex4ht, xy-pic, xymatrix

See the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[matrix,arrow,curve,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\test{
  \xymatrix{{a} \ar^-{b}[r] & {c} \ar@<0.7ex>^-{d}[r]\ar@<-0.7ex>_-{e}[r] & {f}}
}
\tracingmacros=1
Compare
\[
  \test
\]
and
\[
  \xymatrix{{a} \ar^-{b}[r] & {c} \ar@<0.7ex>^-{d}[r]\ar@<-0.7ex>_-{e}[r] & {f}}
\]
\end{document}
```

It is very weird that if I put `\xymatrix` part in a macro as above, then `tex4ht` will generate messy pictures. I look for a workaround of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with superscripts, as they are patched by `tex4ht` at `\begin{document}`. Your sample compiles correctly when you move definition of the `\test` macro before `\begin{document}`. Another possibility is to use the `no^` and `no_` command line options, but this may broke other things.

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499677/2891
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[matrix,arrow,curve,cmtip]{xy}

\newcommand\test{%
  \xymatrix{{a} \ar^-{b}[r] & {c} \ar@<0.7ex>^-{d}[r]\ar@<-0.7ex>_-{e}[r] & {f}}
}

\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
Compare
\[
  \test
\]
and
\[
  \xymatrix{{a} \ar^-{b}[r] & {c} \ar@<0.7ex>^-{d}[r]\ar@<-0.7ex>_-{e}[r] & {f}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]